# Why function in template class<T> can't be marked with std::enable_if<T==anEnumValue>?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, language-lawyer, enable-if

Here is the code that compilable and works as intended.  (Thank juanchopanza)

**First version (correct)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

enum EN{ EN1,EN2 };
template<EN T1> class B{
    //#BLOCK
    public: template<EN enLocal=T1> typename  
      std::enable_if<enLocal==EN1,void>::type test(){  //<-- not cute

        std::cout<<"EN1"<<std::endl;   
    }
    public: template<EN enLocal=T1> typename   
      std::enable_if<enLocal==EN2,void>::type test(){  //<-- not cute

        std::cout<<"EN2"<<std::endl;   
    }
    //#END BLOCK
};

int main() {
    B<EN1> b;
    b.test(); //should print "EN1"
    return 0;
}
```

I think the code is hard to read and not cute.

Thus, I tried *improve* readability the `#BLOCK` to the below code, but it is no longer compilable.
Why?  ... I think this second version is far easier to understand for me.

**Second version (uncompilable)**

```
//#BLOCK
public: typename std::enable_if<T1==EN1,void>::type test(){  //<-- cute
    std::cout<<"EN1"<<std::endl;   
}
public: typename std::enable_if<T1==EN2,void>::type test(){  //<-- cute
   //^ error: functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded
    std::cout<<"EN2"<<std::endl;   
}
//#END BLOCK
```

More specifically, which C++ language specification that makes the second version uncompilable?

Why can't I put `T1` inside `std::enable_if<>`?

I am new to C++.

Comment: `public` outside a class? What are the exact error messages you get?

Comment: No, it is in a class, put it to replace the #BLOCK -- #END BLOCK  .... The error is "functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded".

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think it is just the block of relevant code from the inside class.

Comment: @juanchopanza  Thank again.  Yay, a good duplicated link.

Comment: [`enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) is working during overload resolution of **function templates**, which `test()` in second version are not.

Comment: @w1ck3dg0ph3r  Thank.  That is a valuable knowledge. I will sure read it!